# Supply secret key via environment variable or JVM argument?

Tags: java, linux, windows, environment-variables, jvm-arguments

I have a JVM application hosted on a cloud that needs a secret key for something.
I have considered various ways to supply this key to the app. The app can run on Windows or Linux.

1. Set key as an OS environment variable (`set someInnocuousName=secretkey`); read the key using `System.getenv`.
2. Set key as a JVM argument (`-DsomeInnocuousName=secretkey`), read key using `System.getProperty` and reset the property using `System.setProperty`).
3. Set part of the key in source code.

I can do 3 AND either of 1 OR 2. 
Which out of 1 or 2 is more secure in the event of a server compromise?
I am inclined towards 2. Once I supply the key using JVM arguments, how well can I "cover its tracks"?

What are the pros and cons of 1 and 2?

Also any other suggestions for storing the key are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and used option 2:

```
    String sharedKey = System.getProperty("aeriosKey");
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(sharedKey)) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ingestor.class).error("System property aeriosKey must be set");
        return;
    }

    String s3env = System.getProperty(S3ENV, DEFAULT_S3_ENV);
    String s3accessKey = System.getProperty(S3ACCESS_KEY);
    String s3secretKey = System.getProperty(S3SECRET_KEY);
    if (!ALLOWED_S3_ENVS.contains(s3env)) {
        error("System property s3env must be unset or one of [" + String.join(",", ALLOWED_S3_ENVS) + "]");
        return;
    }
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(s3accessKey) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(s3secretKey)) {
        error("System properties s3accessKey and s3secretKey must be set");
        return;
    }
```

The advantage to this is that you can switch the keys easily by changing out a .properties file, and you can make that file readable for only the user that is running that particular process if need be. Environment variables are more detached, and are readable by any process in that particular environment.

Comment: My problem is related. The catch with property files is that the key is stored in plaintext and not secure in the event of compromise. I want to encrypt the property files and supply the decryption key when I start the application, and then remove all traces of the key (except in memory).

Comment: Better to require the password for decryption to be entered upon application start, then. Command lines are often logged, so supplying a secret on the command line either via env var (`SOME_VAR=value java -jar <app>`) or via a java parameter (`java -DsomeVar=value -jar <app>`) would potentially expose the secret. The application absolutely must be able to be started non-interactively, then the security of the surrounding system *must* be trusted - you're just shifting the risk around otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Type "history" on the command line in Windows and Linux and you'll see why putting secret stuff in the command line is a bad idea.  If that doesn't scare you "Google" for "Where is my command history stored" and "How can a hacker access my command history".

Preferred method is to use a "Priviledged Access Manager" app such as CyberArk or Thycotic or Centrify.  Another alternative is public and private keys and SSH.  This allows passwordless auth and is considered secure.

Worst case, use a key with a SALT and secure encryption algorithm . . . and make sure the key is safe (BTW, "safe" is difficult in today's world).

There are lots of penetration test companies out there.  You could try calling them.  If they've had a good day you might get free advice.